# Menu Handler for the activities

Tags: java, android

Please help me out regarding the menu handler . I want to make menu handler which i can call in different activities . All things are working fine . list is fetching from the server and menu are also appearing but when i click on the any menu button "Force to close" Pops up .

Here is the meun handler class

```
package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MenuHandler extends Activity{
    private Activity activity;

    public MenuHandler(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = activity.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.settings:     
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowSettings.class);
                  startActivity(intent);
            break;
            case R.id.services:     
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Test.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
              break;
            case R.id.Quit: 
                
                finish();
                
                    
            
                break;
            default:    
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

over here i want the same menu to work .

package com.droidnova.android.howto.optionmenu;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Test extends ListActivity  {
    private MenuHandler menuHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        menuHandler = new MenuHandler(this);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        
        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://midsweden.gofreeserve.com/fetch.php");
                
        try{
            
            JSONArray  earthquakes = json.getJSONArray("earthquakes");
            
            for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);
                
                map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("name"));
                map.put("password", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("password"));
                mylist.add(map);            
            }       
        }catch(JSONException e)        {
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
        
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist , R.layout.test, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });
        
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        
        final ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {              
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        return menuHandler.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return menuHandler.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here is what i am getting in the logcat
[image]

Comment: What errors do you see in logcat?

Comment: sorry what do u mean by logcat ?

Comment: That is the window in the debug view in eclipse that shows the log from your android device / emulator. it also shows the exception details when the app crashes (look for the red lines)

Comment: oh . Actually i am running directly on my android phone and over there is says "The application ....(process com. . . )  has stopped unexp"

Comment: It'l be much harder to help this way, but make sure that all of your activities are listed in the manifest xml (ShowSettings and Test)

Comment: @umar You can use connect your device via USB and use logcat to view the system log. You'll have a much easier time finding out the problem after seeing the Exception that's causing it.

Comment: now i managed to get to get the logcat from the emulator please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any specific logcat feedback about the exception your code is throwing, my best guess is Android doesn't like you crossing multiple `Context` instances in the way that you are by instantiating one `Activity` inside of another.

A much better way to accomplish your goal is to use the `MenuHandler` as the base class for any `Activity` that you want to display the menu.  In other words:

- Leave `MenuHandler` alone, except for getting rid of that constructor.
- Make all your `Activity` classes extend `MenuHandler` to bring in that functionality.